# AirCrack-NG suite: some tools like besside-ng were not installed on my Linux distro

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, package-management, kali-linux, aircrack-ng

> Even when this is an Ubuntu issue, I think this is the proper forum to
>   ask about it, due to this problem will probably reproduce in any other
>   Linux distribution.

I have installed **Ubuntu Linux 14.04.2LTS** and added [AirCrack-NG](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/) (for wireless auditing) suite by following [official docs](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_aircrack#installing_aircrack-ng_from_source) too (the Ubuntu repositories `aircrack-ng` package was obsolete).

But now I am not able to find the `besside-ng` program:

```
luis@Zarzamoro:~/Temporal/aircrack-ng$ sudo find / -name "besside-ng*"
/usr/local/share/man/man8/besside-ng.8
/usr/local/share/man/man1/besside-ng-crawler.1
```

On another computer I have then installed [Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/downloads/), and this one seems to have besside-ng inside:

```
luis@VirtuKali:~$ sudo find / -name "besside-ng*"
/usr/bin/besside-ng-crawler
/usr/share/man/man8/besside-ng.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/besside-ng-crawler.1.gz
/usr/sbin/besside-ng
```

I have tried **copying** the `/usr/sbin/besside-ng` file from Kali to Ubuntu, but, even when the program starts, it seems **not to behave** all right:

```
luis@Zarzamoro:~/testing/besside-ng$ sudo besside-ng wlan0mon -v
[16:56:10] mac 00:1a:ef:17:79:ff
[16:56:10] Let's ride
[16:56:10] Logging to besside.log
[16:56:10] Found AP f8:7f:39:a3:f4:21 [MOVISTAR_F418] chan 11 crypto WPA dbm -28
[16:56:10] Found AP f8:63:94:aa:0f:2b [MOVISTAR_0F22] chan 10 crypto WPA dbm -72
besside-ng: wi_read(): No such file or directory
luis@Zarzamoro:~/testing/besside-ng$ sudo besside-ng wlan0mon -v
[16:56:28] mac 00:1a:ef:17:79:ff
[16:56:28] Let's ride
[16:56:28] Resuming from besside.log
[16:56:28] Appending to wpa.cap
[16:56:28] Appending to wep.cap
[16:56:28] Logging to besside.log
besside-ng: wi_read(): No child processes
```

What could I do to **make besside-ng work**?
It seems to be a part of the AirCrack-NG suite, so I can not install it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when they have been working very well during years, some features of AirCrack-NG are still considered as **experimental**, so you need to install the **SVN development** version to obtain them (Kali Linux includes it, but Ubuntu repositories don't):

**Compile SVN version** adding experimental features:

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
$ svn co http://svn.aircrack-ng.org/trunk/ aircrack-ng
$ cd aircrack-ng
$ make sqlite=true experimental=true
# make sqlite=true experimental=true install
```

According to [official docs](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_aircrack#latest_svn_with_airolib-ng_support_and_experimental_unstable_programs_requires_sqlite_installed), this SVN version adds some tools `like Tkiptun-ng, Easside-ng (and buddy-ng), Wesside-ng and Besside-ng`.

You can even add what the [papers](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_aircrack#latest_svn_with_airolib-ng_and_and_experimental_unstable_programs_plus_external_scripts) call `external scripts like Airoscript-ng, Versuck-ng, Airgraph-ng and Airdrop-ng` if the make options are:

```
make sqlite=true experimental=true ext_scripts=true
make sqlite=true experimental=true ext_scripts=true install
```